# Minify using pom.xml

Tags: pom.xml, minify

is it possible to minify css and js files inside a specific folder and then use the minified files for a file, let's say the index.html.? Im thinking of using the pom.xml then use the maven-minify-plugin and the replacer plugin but I can't find a good structure.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the static-helper-maven-plugin from WUIC project (http://wuic.github.io/)

The maven plugin relies on WUIC to parse the index.html of your workspace, collects js/css used inside it, resolve them, minify them, aggregate them and rewrite the index.html with a version number in URLs to burst client cache in case of any change.

wiki: https://github.com/wuic/wuic/wiki/Process-at-build-time

The WUIC's website is generated optimized with this approach:
- source: https://github.com/wuic/wuic.github.io
- result: https://github.com/wuic/wuic.github.io/tree/master

Comment: Hello Guillaume, i can't found any example of how can i use static-helper-maven-plugin to parse a specific html page in my webapp, collect used js/css and minify them, can you point me in the right direction ? thanks

Comment: Hi! Find the doc here: http://wuic.github.io/tutorials.html#_process_at_build_time and the sample here: https://github.com/wuic/wuic-samples/tree/wuic-0.5.x-snapshot/build-time-sample

Comment: Also check the WUIC site that is a good example of HTML page processing: https://github.com/wuic/wuic.github.io